# Creating a new dict by updating an existing one

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to create a new dictionary, by updating an existing one. This behaves as supposed:

```
x = {'a': 1}
x.update({'a': 2})
```

But why does the following results in a NoneType?

```
({'a': 1}).update({'a': 2})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*All* in-place operations in the Python standard library return `None`, `dict.update()` is no exception.

You cannot create a `dict` literal and call `.update()` on that and expect it to return the updated `dict` object, no.

You essentially are doing this:

```
tmp = {'a': 1}
result = tmp.update({'a': 2})
del tmp
```

and expect `result` to be the dictionary.

You *could* use:

```
dict({'a': 1}, **{'a': 2})
```

and get a merged dictionary, however. Or, for a more practical looking version:

```
copy = dict(original, foo='bar')
```

creating a copy of a dictionary plus setting some extra keys (replacing any previous value for that key).

In Python 3.5 and newer you’d use:

```
copy = {**original, 'foo': 'bar'}
```

Comment: thx, that not only solves my problem, but also explains what i did wrong

Answer (score 1):

Because `update`, like all mutating methods in Python, returns None.